# Sequelize adding association

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, sequelize.js, models

I'm trying to add association to my organization model but am having problems with the .add part of sequelize. I defined the association as such:

```
models.organisation.hasMany(models.event, {
      foreignKey: 'organisationKey'
    });
```

And when an organization and an event has been created I tried to associate them through the following code:

```
organisation.addmodels.event(event);
```

I got this from the sequelize docs which says that you should do something like this: where I'm guessing that the "project" and "event" is supposed to be created objects and the "Project" is supposed to be the sequelize model.

```
project.addProject(project)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the syntax which could be solved by storing the model in a variable as such:

```
var Event = models.event;
organisation.addEvent(event);
```

Not the cleanest solution but it works.